# Не работает join в socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Начинаю знакомиться с node js и socket.io. Пишу простую игру крестики-нолики, в которой человек, зашедший по ссылке localhost:3000 (хост игры) получает сгенерированую ссылку, в запросе которой его id, равный также id комнаты по умолчанию. Он отправляет ссылку другу, сервер получает id из ссылки и должен присоединить гостя в комнату хоста игры.

Сервер:

```
socket.on('link', function(link){
    console.log(link);
    var str = urlapi.parse(link).search;
    if (str) {
        roomID = str.replace('?', '').toString();
        socket.join(roomID); // <---- Это не работает
    }
    else {
        socket.emit('link', socket.id);
    }        
});
```

Клиент:

```
var link = window.location.href;
socket.emit('link', link);
socket.on('link', function(roomID){
            $('#link').text(window.location.href+'?'+roomID);
            $('#link').attr('href',window.location.href+'?'+roomID);
        });
```

Comment: а где ж там join? и в документации про .push я что-то не вижу упоминания

Comment: Да, верно, поправил. Спасибо. Кучу вариантов перепробовал, в том числе и push, но сам join не работает.

Comment: а что значит "не работает"? что пишет в лог? что в `str`? что в `roomID`?

Comment: В str попадает строка запроса, типа ?xk0ye-oKE3YLtBxOAAAC.
В roomID тоже самое только без знака вопроса.
С логами не разобрался ещё.

Comment: И ещё. join работает сразу после io.sockets.on('connection'... , но не в socket.on...

Comment: ну, вообще полный гугл ответов на "socket.join not working". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697199/socket-io-rooms-doesnt-work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244553/socket-io-joining-a-room-registers-the-room-but-only-joins-an-empty-string-room